# Teradata SQL - Llenar con el último valor no nulo

Tags: sql, teradata

Tengo una tabla en TERADATA que se ve así:

```
Account_Num Install_Due_Dt  Install_Num Install_Pay_Dt
12805196    12/08/2019                1     12/08/2019
?           10/09/2019                2              ?
?           10/10/2019                3              ?
?           11/11/2019                4              ?
?           10/12/2019                5              ?
```

Necesito completar la columna Install_Pay_Dt con el último valor no nulo. Usaría la función LAG pero tengo la versión 15 de TERADATA y no la incluye. He probado con un código como el que sigue:

```
coalesce(Install_Pay_Dt, MAX(lag_) 
OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY Install_Num asc
ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) as lag
```

Pero solamente me completa la segunda fila. 
La columna install_num se usa para ordenar mientras que Account_num es el ID

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE riesgos_users.borrar ,FALLBACK ,
 NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
 NO AFTER JOURNAL,
 CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
 DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
 MAP = TD_MAP1
 (
    Account_Num INTEGER, 
    Install_Due_Dt DATE,
    Install_Num INTEGER,
    Install_Pay_Dt DATE
  )
NO PRIMARY INDEX ;

insert into riesgos_users.borrar
values (12805196,'2019/08/12' (DATE),1,'2019/08/12' (DATE));

insert into riesgos_users.borrar
values (NULL,'2019/09/10' (DATE),2,NULL);

insert into riesgos_users.borrar
values (NULL,'2019/10/10' (DATE),3,NULL);

insert into riesgos_users.borrar
values (NULL,'2019/11/11' (DATE),4,NULL);

insert into riesgos_users.borrar
values (NULL,'2019/12/10' (DATE),5,NULL);

insert into riesgos_users.borrar
values (12805198,'2020/01/10' (DATE),6,'2020/01/10' (DATE));

insert into riesgos_users.borrar
values (NULL,'2020/02/10' (DATE),7,NULL);


--SELECT * FROM riesgos_users.borrar ORDER BY 2 ASC

select     A.Account_Num,A.Install_Due_Dt,A.Install_Num,A.Install_Pay_Dt,COALESCE(A.Install_Pay_Dt,CRUZAR.Install_Pay_Dt) COLOCAR 
from riesgos_users.borrar as A

LEFT JOIN (select Account_Num,Install_Due_Dt,Install_Num,Install_Pay_Dt,
        COALESCE((MAX(Install_Pay_Dt) OVER(ORDER BY Install_Pay_Dt asc
        ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING)),('2999/01/01' (DATE))) as     fecha_pago_PROXIMO
            FROM 
            (select Account_Num,Install_Due_Dt,Install_Num,Install_Pay_Dt
            from riesgos_users.borrar 
            where Install_Pay_Dt is not null) AS TABLA
            )AS CRUZAR

on  A.Install_Due_Dt >= CRUZAR.Install_Pay_Dt
AND A.Install_Due_Dt < CRUZAR.FECHA_PAGO_PROXIMO
ORDER BY A.Install_Due_Dt
```

[image: espero sea esto lo que buscas... esta en Teradata]

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo tu respuesta responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].